# Problema quanto ao tipo em função com parâmetros variáveis em C

Tags: c, c++

Estou com dificuldade em resolver um problema em uma função que recebe parâmetros variáveis. Tenho uma função que Soma uma quantidade variável de números, seu primeiro parâmetro é a quantidade de números a serem somados, e os outros são os números em si, ela funciona quando trabalho com números double, mas não quando utilizo números do tipo int, compilando esse código o output será 60.00, como esperado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

double somaVariaveis(int qtd, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int i;
    double soma = 0;

    va_start(args, qtd);

    for(i = 0; i < qtd; i++)
        soma += va_arg(args, double);

    va_end(args);

    return soma;
}

int main()
{
    printf("soma de parametros variaveis: %.2lf", somaVariaveis(3, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0));

    return 0;
}
```

Agora, caso eu tente imprimir a soma de números inteiros:

```
printf("soma de parametros variaveis: %.2lf", somaVariaveis(3, 10, 20, 30));
```

O resultado será 0.00;

Onde eu errei? Não deveria ter ocorrido cast quando passo variáveis do tipo int e especifico que quero variáveis double? Percebi certa dificuldade ao se trabalhar com parâmetros variáveis em relação ao tipo, em outro exemplo, caso eu tente somar parâmetros do tipo float:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

float somaVariaveis(int qtd, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int i;
    float soma = 0;

    va_start(args, qtd);

    for(i = 0; i < qtd; i++)
        soma += va_arg(args, float);

    va_end(args);

    return soma;
}

int main()
{
    printf("soma de parametros variaveis: %.2f", somaVariaveis(3, 10.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f));
    return 0;
}
```

Recebo o seguinte Warning, e tenho um problema de execução.:

warning: 'float' is promoted to 'double' when passed through '...'

note: (so you should pass 'double' not 'float' to 'va_arg')

note: if this code is reached, the program will abort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que fazer o cast de `int` para `double`.

Com este protótipo `double somaVariaveis(int qtd, ...)` esta função aceita parâmetros de qualquer tipo no lugar dos 3 pontinhos. No caso geral não tem como o compilador saber de qual maneira os parâmetros serão interpretados pela função chamada.

Quanto ao segundo programa, a mensagem é bem explicativa: quando você passa parâmetros `float` para uma função, o compilador "promove" o `float` para `double` quando a função é chamada. No entanto, sua função considera parâmetros `float`, e como os tamanhos de `float` e `double` são diferentes, seu programa provavelmente vai abortar, pois a pilha de execução (stack) vai ficar corrompida.

Os dois casos são parecidos.

Isso deve acontecer também se sua função com `va_args` tratar `char`, e você passar `char` na chamada, porque em chamada de função (se não me engano) parâmetros `char` são promovidos para `int`.

Comment: Mas como fazer o cast nesse caso? pois em va_arg, já preciso informar o tipo que eu quero converter o parâmetro passado.

Comment: Se for constante use 10. , 20. , 30. etc, ou então se achar melhor 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, etc (ou seja, coloque o ponto decimal). Se for uma variável use (double)i em C, double(i) em C++...se for uma expressão use (double)(a+b etc) em C, double(a+b etc) em C++. Na verdade em C++ existem formas de cast mais aconselháveis, mas eu não as uso.

Comment: Entendi, você está falando pra fazer um cast explicito no momento da passagem de parâmetros. O que eu queria era exatamente um maneira de conseguir passar como um inteiro e mesmo assim conseguir convertê-lo em double dentro da função.

Comment: Quando você usa os 3 pontinhos não tenho jeito, você tem que passar os parâmetros do tipo que a função espera internamente. Agora, se você usa C++ normalmente não é necessário usar funções com números variáveis de parâmetros, C++ tem muito mais recursos que C, principalmente se você usa C++11 ou C++14.

Answer (score 0):

Cara com cast explicito funfô.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

double somaVariaveis(int qtd, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int i;
    double soma = 0;

    va_start(args, qtd);

    for(i = 0; i < qtd; i++)
        soma += va_arg(args, double);

    va_end(args);

    return soma;
}

int main()
{
    printf("soma de parametros variaveis: %.2lf", somaVariaveis(3, (double) 10, (double) 20, (double) 30));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se for trabalhar só com valores numéricos, o casting trabalha bem com array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double soma(int qtd, double s[]){
    double ret=0;
    for(int i=0;i<qtd;i++){
        ret+=s[i];
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{   
    int arg1=8;
    float arg2=4.3,arg3=5;
    double arg4=2.2,arg5=4;
    double n[100]={arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,1,16.4};
    printf("\nsoma de parametros variaveis: %.2lf\n\n", soma(7, n));
    n[7]=200.0;
    printf("\nsoma de parametros variaveis: %.2lf\n\n", soma(8, n));
    return 0;
}
```